# how to download UBUNTU 12.04(.4)

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I lost my UBUNTU 12.04 from my NOTEBOOK. How to get/download UBUNTU 12.04?

My notebook driver (dell insp 14 3442) is just compatible with UBUNTU 12.04. 
I have searched in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, but only Ubuntu 14.04 is listed

Comment: I have never seen ubuntu providing Serivce Packs! They just provide package updates!

Comment: Service packs are a Windows concept, not a Linux/Unix concept. The currently supported versions of Ubuntu are 12.04.4 and 14.04. If you don't have Ubuntu, I recommend trying out Ubuntu 14.04, as it will be supported until 2019.

Comment: here you can get Ubuntu 12.04.4 ISO file, http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/

Answer (score 0):

From your model number, I suspect you have either a NVIDIA® GeForce® 820M or an Intel® HD Graphics 4400, in wich case I recommend using Ubuntu 14.04.

Anyway, download [here](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/) *(try to use Torrent files if you know what they are, otherwise just get the .iso)*

You can find additional information on installing drivers for your graphic card if that's the issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)